# Faster QuickSort

Tags: java, sorting, quick-sort, insertion-sort

I'm trying to make my QuickSort faster than it is and I have got no more ideas about how to make it more efficient for all types of arrays but mostly very big arrays. It uses random to create the Pivot and it uses InsertionSort when the array is less than 15 elements. What do you think guys?
I appreciate for any help here to make the code run faster.

```
public class QuickSort
    private static Random rand = new Random();
    public void sort(int[] v){

        QuickSort(v, 0, v.length-1);
    }

    private void QuickSort (int[] v, int first, int last) {

        if (first >= last)
            return;
        else {
            if (last - first < 15) {
                InsertionSort(v, first, last);
                return;
            }
            int[] pivotLoc = partitionArray(v, first, last, makePivot(v,first,last));
            QuickSort(v, first, pivotLoc[1]);
            QuickSort(v, pivotLoc[0], last);
        }

    }

    private int[] partitionArray (int[] v, int first, int last, int pivot) {

        while(last => first) {

            while(v[first] < pivot) first++;
            while(v[last] > pivot) last--;
            if (first > last) break;
            swap(v, first, last);
            first++;
            last--;
        }
        return new int[] {first, last};
    }

    private void swap(int[] v, int first, int last) {
        int temp = v[first];
        v[first] = v[last];
        v[last] = temp;
    }

    public void InsertionSort(int[] v, int first, int last) {
        int temp;
        for (int i=first + 1; i <= last; i++) {
            int j = i;
            while (j > 0 && v[j-1] > (v[j]) ) {
                temp = v[j];
                v[j] = v[j-1]; 
                v[j-1] = temp; 
                j--;
            }
        }
    }

    private int makePivot (int[] v, int first, int last){
        return v[rand.nextInt(last-first+1)+first];
    }

}
```

Comment: (1) Your implementation runs into stack overflow. (2) You omitted `{` after `public class QuickSort`. (3) There is no `=>` in Java.

Answer (score 1):

As quick sort is a [divide and conquer algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms) you can do these steps

```
QuickSort(v, first, pivotLoc[1]);
QuickSort(v, pivotLoc[0], last);
```

in parallel. Here is [a good start point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Parallelization) for this area.

PS also method `swap` may be reused in your `InsertionSort` method.

Comment: But there is a point where the overhead of the thread communication will make it slower than just throwing a single thread at it.

Comment: @ratchetfreak what thread communication and what overhead do you mean?

Comment: Allocating the Jobs, pushing them to a thread-safe queue, spinning up new threads if needed (which need to pull from that thread-safe queue), waiting on and collecting the "done" signals from the jobs.  Only use parallelism when the individual jobs are big enough to warrant all that.

Comment: I have heard about doing it in parallell but where I use this class doesn't allow it.

Comment: Good point about the swap. Got it right! Thanks!

Comment: @Dadelante you haven't mentioned about prohibition for using parallelism in your question. What is the real purpose of your code? Is this a task for QuickSort impl in a class or some real sorting task?

Comment: @ratchetfreak in theory, you are right. Practically, with _accurate_ impl, the parallel sort execution allows increase performance significantly. Moreover, standard Java [Fork/Join framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) may be used for impl which takes care about low level thread things to itself.

Comment: @Dadelante I test the code by putting it in kattis to see how much faster it can get. Kattis doesn't allow parallelism. There are several hundreds of tests that this code will go throw in kattis.

Comment: @Dadelante you can see standard JDK Dual-Pivot Quicksort impl in class `java.util.DualPivotQuicksort#sort(int[] a, int left, int right, boolean leftmost)`. There are some optimizations. E.g. they use 47 value for INSERTION_SORT_THRESHOLD